# how to declare modules that has other modules in Flowtype?

Tags: flowtype

I have a simple package consisting of one index.js that includes myservices.js, and the latter further requires net.js and info.js, 
how to declare this package in flowtype? Thanks,

```
// myservices.js
"use strict";

module.exports.net = require('./net.js')
module.exports.info = require('./info.js')


// index.js
module.exports = require('./build/lib/myservices');
```

Comment: check this out https://github.com/entria/graphql-mongoose-loader

Answer (score 0):

so far, following works:

```
type netT = {
  get_info : (URL : string) => any
}

declare module 'myservices' {
    declare var net : netT
    declare var info : any
}
```